# Hide/show toolbar on tap

Tags: cocoa-touch, toolbar, tap

Because I have an wallpaper app , I want that wehen you open the app there is no toolbar and that when you tap on the screen the toolbar comes , tap again and it goes away.  How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the toolbar's alpha value like so:

To Hide:

```
toolbar.alpha = 0.0;
```

To Show:

```
 toolbar.alpha = 1.0;
```

Example:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
// self.navigationController.toolbar.alpha = 0.0;
// or
// toolbar.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the uiimageview of your wallpaper add a method call touchesEnded: this will be called when you have touched the imaheView. The set hide the toolbat [toolbar setHidden:Yes animated:Yes];

Comment: Where to put the `[toolbar setHidden:Yes animated:Yes]` ? In the ViewDidLoad ? Thanks

Comment: Then when you want to hide your toolbar